# How can I plot a picture with this kind of legend?

Tags: graphics, legending

[image]

Can "plotlegend" do that? I cannot find a proper function.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=legend ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
      PlotStyle   -> {Blue, Red}, 
      PlotLegends -> Placed[Framed@LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"L1", "L2"}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
                            Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: What you use is mathematica 8 or 9? I cannot plot the picture like the above one to use mathematica 8.

Comment: @user10709 Those functions have been added in version 9. I don't have v8 available now to play with. Please when you want a solution for a problem in a previous version, state that at the question.